# Adding an amount constraint on a has_many relationship without making it impossible to validate the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, relationship, has-many

I'm building an app which should display a list of works. Each work is represented by the `Work` model and can have multiple pictures, represented by the `WorkPicture` model.

**work.rb**

```
class Work < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  has_many :pictures, class_name: "WorkPicture", dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, allow_destroy: true

  # Ensures that we have at least 1 picture
  validates :pictures, length: { minimum: 1, message: "are not enough." } 

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true

end
```

I'm using the line `validates :pictures, length: { minimum: 1, message: "are not enough." }` to make sure that any instance of this model has at least one picture attached to it.

---

Here is the model for the pictures (it uses the `paperclip` gem for the attached picture):

**work_picture.rb**

```
class WorkPicture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :work

  CONVERT_OPTIONS = "-gravity north"
  has_attached_file    :picture, styles:          { big: ["945x584#", :png], thumb: ["360x222#", :png] },
                                 convert_options: { big: CONVERT_OPTIONS, thumb: CONVERT_OPTIONS }
  validates_attachment :picture, presence:        true,
                                 content_type:    { content_type: /image/ }
end
```

---

I am having trouble testing the relationship between these two models. Here is how I'm trying to set them up using the `factory_girl` gem:

**factories.rb**

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do    
  factory :work do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Project #{n}" }
    description     "A description"
    category

    after :build do |work, evaluator|
      create(:work_picture, work: work) # Creating a picture for this work
    end
  end

  factory :category do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Category #{n}" }
  end

  factory :work_picture do
    picture { fixture_file_upload Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/files/work.png"), "image/png" }
    work

    after :create do |work_picture, evaluator|
      evaluator.picture.close
    end
  end
end
```

In the `:work_picture` factory, I simply add a predefined picture to it.

In the `:work` factory, I try to add a picture to a work when it has just been created, but this cannot be done because `work_picture` **would need a valid id for it to be associated correctly** with the work, and that's not possible because the work I'm creating has not been saved and thus has no id.

I need a way to associate a picture to it when it is built (before it is saved), because when the work is saved it validates the number of pictures it has, and since it hasn't been associated with any picture yet, the validations won't pass and it still won't have an id for the pictures.

If you think about it, it turns out to be a bit of a paradox because the picture requires a work with an id to be associated to it, but a work needs a picture before it can be assigned an id, so none of the two conditions rely on the other's existence before they can come true.

Here's my spec for the `Work` model:

**work_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Work do
  let!(:work) { build(:work) }
  subject { work }

  it { should respond_to :name }
  it { should respond_to :description }
  it { should respond_to :category }
  it { should respond_to :category_id }

  it { should respond_to :pictures }

  it { should be_valid } # Fails, because we have no picture

  # ... Unrelated tests omitted

  # This test is here to check if the factory_girl setup is working
  describe "picture count" do
    it "should be 1" do
      expect(work.pictures.count).to eq 1 # Fails, because we are unable to add the picture
    end
  end
end
```

---

## My question

How can I solve this so that the requirement for at least one picture being present on the model remains in place, but at the same time I will be able to create (and save) an instance of it before it is associated with a picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the first line of work_picture.rb to

```
belongs_to :work, inverse_of: :pictures
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if that works as the first thing in thr morning tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry, I just tried this and it didn't seem to work. I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution. After fiddling around in the console I discovered that, using `work.pictures.build`, I could create a dummy `work_picture` that is bound to my model even without it being saved. This makes it possible to associate a picture to it and pass the validations before the save. Once saved, everything works okay.

Here are the changes I've made:

**factories.rb**

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

FactoryGirl.define do
  # ...

  factory :work do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Project #{n}" }
    description     "A cool description"
    category

    after :build do |work|
      work_picture = work.pictures.build # Builds a dummy picture
      work_picture.update_attributes(attributes_for(:work_picture)) # Loads the picture file
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

---

I've also tweaked my tests to verify that everything works right:

**work_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Work do

  # ...

  # Checks if the factory_girl setup is working
  describe "picture length" do
    it "should be 1" do
      expect(work.pictures.length).to eq 1
    end
  end

  describe "picture count after save" do
    before { work.save }

    it "should be 1" do
      expect(work.pictures.count).to eq 1
    end
  end
end
```